# Minimum increment decrement operations to make array non increasing

Tags: arrays

> Given an array a, your task is to convert it into a non-increasing
>   form such that we can either increment or decrement the array value by
>   1 in minimum changes possible.
>
> Examples :
>
> Input : a[] = {3, 1, 2, 1} Output : 1 Explanation : We can convert the
>   array into 3 1 1 1 by changing 3rd element of array i.e. 2  into its
>   previous integer 1 in one step hence only one step is required.
>
> Input : a[] = {3, 1, 5, 1} Output : 4 We need to decrease 5 to 1 to
>   make array sorted in non-increasing order.
>
> Input : a[] = {1, 5, 5, 5} Output : 4 We need to increase 1 to 5.

This is the problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-incrementdecrement-to-make-array-non-increasing/

The solution given is wrong. It is failing for this test case

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. The answer should be 6 with all array elements converted into 3. But the code gives 4 as the output. I don't think it is a greedy algorithm problem. What should be the approach.

Comment: please copy paste problem from geeksforgeeks to here in your question.

Comment: Added the problem Statement

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed that's why I have asked. I think it is dp problem and the only thing I can think of at this time is:  for every element which is greater than its previous element, either we can decrease it or increase all the previous elements and find the minimum cost.

Answer (score 1):

The code given in gfg is correct, you must have missed the part where they have pushed the element twice, one time inside the if and other outside the if condition
P.S. I am also looking for the logic behind it.